# SQL Query incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm doing some past question papers and came across the following: 
A company uses the following database:

```
customers - CustNo, CustName, CustAddress
Reservations - CustNo, TourID
Tours - TourID, Destination, Date, Time, Price
```

From these tables I have to create an SQL statement for finding the customer numbers of passengers who are booked on both any tour to London and also any tour to Edinburgh...

The attempt is this:

```
SELECT 
    R.custNo 
FROM 
    Reservations R, Tours T 
WHERE
    T.tourID = R.tourID 
    AND T.destination = 'London' 
    AND T.destination = 'Edinburgh';
```

I have been told this is not correct and to find an alternative, correct, SQL statement. So if anyone can help me out with this question it'd be great.

Comment: Which RDBMS  are you using – MySQL, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Once you figure out how to do JOINs, you can join the tours table twice: once for Edinburgh and once for London. But the 'give the man a fish' answer provided below is the more conventional response

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
select R.custNo
from Reservations R
join Tours T on T.tourID = R.tourID
where T.destination in ('London', 'Edinburgh')
group by R.custNo
having count(distinct T.destination) = 2
```

This will look for customers that have `'London'` or `'Edinburgh'` destinations and retrieve only those, that have both.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R1.custNo 
FROM Reservations R1 inner join Tours T1 on T1.tourID = R1.tourID
WHERE T1.destination = 'London' 
INTERSECT
SELECT R2.custNo 
FROM Reservations R2 inner join Tours T2 on T2.tourID = R2.tourID
WHERE T2.destination = 'Edinburgh'
```

ps: this will work only on sql server DBMS